# pythonic style to filter data in csvs

Tags: python, string, list, csv, set

I have a folder of 1000's of csv files on specific datasets. For each dataset, I have three types of data. The naming convention is as follows:

(assuming name of dataset is 'aaa')

1. `'aaa_values.csv'`
2. `'aaa_info.csv'`
3. `'aaaps.csv'`

Each dataset has a title of varying length e.g., 'aaa', 'ab3fz', 'gjt89', etc. Note the third type of data has no underscore separating the type - it is `'ps.csv'`

I would like to filter this to obtain the universe of datasets. I have managed to do this with the following Python code, but it is clunky and not very 'Pythonic'.

Does anyone have suggestions for a more elegant way of doing this?

```
import os
x = []
y = os.listdir("C:\\Anaconda3\\Python_Library\\Python_Folder\\csvData")
for i in y:
    x.append(i.split('_'))
h = []
for i in x:
    for j in i:
        h.append(j)
c = [l for l in h if l != 'values.csv']
c = list(set([p for p in c if p != 'info.csv']))
[t for t in c if t[-6:]!='ps.csv']
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step to a more pythonic code is using more descriptive names than `x`, `y`, `i`, `j`, `c`, and `p`. This looks a bit better:

```
# paths = os.listdir("C:\\Anaconda3\\Python_Library\\Python_Folder\\csvData")
paths = ['aaa_values.csv', 'aaa_info.csv', 'aaaps.csv', 'bbbps.csv', 'ccc_info.csv']
res = set()
for path in paths:
    path_parts = path.split('_')
    last = path_parts[-1]
    if (last == 'values.csv' or last == 'info.csv'):
        res.add(path_parts[0])
    elif last[-6:] == 'ps.csv':
        res.add(last[:-6])
```

Now:

```
>>> res
{'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a set to remove duplicates, and use `find()` to check for and locate the '_' in the filename:

```
import os

path = "C:\\Anaconda3\\Python_Library\\Python_Folder\\csvData"
suffixlength = len('ps.csv')

# use a set to remove duplicates
datasets = set()

for filename in os.listdir(path):

    # find() returns the index of the '_' or -1 if it isn't found.   
    i = filename.find('_')

    # chop the filename at the index of the '_' if found else just
    # before the 'ps.csv' suffix
    datasets.add(filename[:i] if i>0 else filename[:-suffixlength])
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)** and **[set comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)** are very Pythonic, so to extend on Mike Muller's example:

```
import re
import os

# see https://regex101.com/r/sR5cQ8 for the regex explanation
dataset_re = re.compile(r'^(.*)(?:_values|_info|ps)\.csv$')

# paths = os.listdir("C:\\Anaconda3\\Python_Library\\Python_Folder\\csvData")
paths = ['aaa_values.csv', 'aaa_info.csv', 'aaaps.csv',
         'bbbps.csv', 'ccc_info.csv', 'README.txt']
dataset_universe = {match for path in paths
                          for match in dataset_re.findall(path)}

dataset_universe  # {'aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'}
```

---

Regex explanation copied from https://regex101.com/r/sR5cQ8:

```
^ assert position at start of the string
1st Capturing group (.*)
    .* matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: * Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
(?:_values|_info|ps) Non-capturing group
    1st Alternative: _values
        _values matches the characters _values literally (case sensitive)
    2nd Alternative: _info
        _info matches the characters _info literally (case sensitive)
    3rd Alternative: ps
        ps matches the characters ps literally (case sensitive)
\. matches the character . literally
csv matches the characters csv literally (case sensitive)
$ assert position at end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of doing it using [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

> **Consider your input folder contains files like this:**

```
aaa_info.csv
aaa_values.csv
aaapd.csv
bbb_info.csv
bbb_values.csv
bbbpd.csv
ccc_info.csv
ccc_values.csv
cccpd.csv
ddd_info.csv
ddd_values.csv
dddpd.csv
```

> **CODE**

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

#Get all the csv files in the folder
flist = [os.path.basename(x) for x in glob.glob(os.getcwd() + '\\*.csv')]

#Create a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()

#Create a column named files and assign the file list to it
df['files'] = flist

#Create another column named set and assign only the portion of the file name that we want to create set by
df['set'] = [x.rsplit('_')[0] if '_' in x else x[:-6] for x in flist]

#Group by the set names required
#if you want the output as sets
dfs = df.groupby(df['set']).apply(lambda x: set(x['files']))

#if you want them to be CSV
dfg = df.groupby(df['set']).apply(lambda x: ','.join(x['files']))

dfg.to_csv('setoffiles.csv')
```

> **Following will be the output produced**

[image]